# Handler's postDelayed's callback: Checking if the FragmentActivity is not null and not destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler

I have written this class:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler the_transition_handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        startTheTransitionAfterTheSplashScreen();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        the_transition_handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    private void startTheTransitionAfterTheSplashScreen() {
        the_transition_handler = new Handler();
        the_transition_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Intent intentSplashScreenToActivityJustAfterSplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ActivityJustAfterSplashScreen.class);
                startActivity(intentSplashScreenToActivityJustAfterSplashScreen);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter_activity, R.anim.animation_leave_activity);
                finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

My question is: since the `run` callback is executed after the time I've indicated (according to this doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) , should I replace its content with the following code (assuming `that` being an `AppCompatActivity`)?

```
@Override
public void run() {

    if(that == null || that.isDestroyed()) {
        return;
    }

    final Intent intentSplashScreenToActivityJustAfterSplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ActivityJustAfterSplashScreen.class);
    startActivity(intentSplashScreenToActivityJustAfterSplashScreen);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter_activity, R.anim.animation_leave_activity);
    finish();
}
```

Note that Android Studio says `that == null` is always false and should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isDestroyed() || isFinishing()` or just call `removeCallbacksAndMessages` to remove any pending posts of callbacks:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (the_transition_handler != null) {
            the_transition_handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Should I use only `isFinishing` or `isDestroyed` or both using OR as you advised? Is `removeCallbacksAndMessages` really sufficient by itself to replace these 1 or 2 booleans?